# Android SQLiteException Syntax error

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

So I'm very new to SQL. I'm trying to take a xml file to make it into a database that I can search. I have a syntax error but can't see it/not familiar enough to see it.
Here is my onCreate method

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sContext = getApplicationContext();
    boolean boot = settings.getBoolean("launch", false);
    if (boot == false) {
        createData();
    }
    dataSource = new StopsDataSource(this);
    dbhelper = new StopsDBHelper(this,"stops",null,1);
    mDatabase = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dataSource.open();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        //Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }
    //MyLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();



    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```

The creatData()

```
 private void createDate() {
    PullParser parser = new PullParser();
    List<Stops> stops = parser.parseXML(this);

    for ( Stops stop: stops) {
        dataSource.create(stop);
    }
}
```

And the DBHelper

```
public class StopsDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_STOPS = "stops";
public static final String COlUMN_ID = "stopID";
public static final String COLUMN_STOP_NAME = "stopName";
public static final String COLUMN_STOP_LAT = "stopLat";
public static final String COLUMN_STOP_LON = "stopLon";
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_STOPS + "(" + COlUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  COlUMN_ID + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_LAT + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_STOP_LON + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
public StopsDBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STOPS);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

}

The error I'm getting is

```
   08-06 19:21:06.041    5784-5784/ccalgary.transit.helper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ccalgary.transit.helper/ccalgary.transit.helper.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEstops": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEstops(stopID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, stopID TEXT, stopLat TEXT, stopLon TEXT, stopName TEXT)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEstops": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEstops(stopID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, stopID TEXT, stopLat TEXT, stopLon TEXT, stopName TEXT)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
        at ccalgary.transit.helper.StopsDBHelper.onCreate(StopsDBHelper.java:25)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at ccalgary.transit.helper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
        ... 11 more
```

It's having issues with the TABLE_CREATE and I can't see anything obviously wrong with it. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you do have syntax error here. Change this line

```
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_STOPS + "(" + COlUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  COlUMN_ID + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_LAT + " TEXT, "
    + COLUMN_STOP_LON + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
```

To this:

```
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STOPS + "(" + COlUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  COlUMN_ID + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_LAT + " TEXT, "
    + COLUMN_STOP_LON + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STOP_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
```

You are just missing a space between TABLE and TableName in your query

Comment: Much nicer answer than mine

Comment: Yea, it used to happen to me all the time in the beginning, thats how you learn, can you mark the answer correct if it solved your problem

Comment: yup, It was just making me wait so long before it would let me choose the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between TABLE and stops. That will most likely fix it. You need to CREATE TABLE stop not CREATE TABLEstop